# Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityToken' token

Tags: wcf, azure, wif

I am trying to use WS2007HttpRelayBinding with end to end security mode set to TransportWithMessageCredential. I am using IssuedToken as the credential type. I get the token from a ADFS 2.0 one calling the service I get the following in the on premises wcf trace log

Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.

update:
This is how I am configuring the service host

```
ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();

            serviceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate = GetServiceCertificateWithPrivateKey();


            serviceConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;


            serviceConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = new X509IssuerNameRegistry("localhost");


            serviceConfiguration.SaveBootstrapTokens = true;


            serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler());


            serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/Service1/"));



            FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost(host, serviceConfiguration);

            host.Open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding security elements is set to look for SAML 1.1 tokens. I added the following code to the server after constructing the ‘CustomBinding’ element

```
IssuedSecurityTokenParameters issuedTokenParameters = 
            myBinding.Elements.Find<TransportSecurityBindingElement>().EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Endorsing[0] as IssuedSecurityTokenParameters;
        issuedTokenParameters.TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0";
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you verify if Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler is added in

```
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler" />
  </securityTokenHandlers>
```

Edit: And also be sure to verify certificates configuration.

Edit: Maybe this will also help [MSDN WCF forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/e8b1db31-1c2e-42eb-850f-4d0b34340ec6)

Comment: I believe this is equalant to this code which I am doing, 

serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.Add(new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler());

and then I call 

FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost(host, serviceConfiguration);

Comment: Here is how I am creating client binding

var binding = new WS2007HttpRelayBinding();
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.IssuedToken;
            binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
            //binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;            
            binding.Security.Mode = EndToEndSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

do not see the problem mentioned in the post

Comment: binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;  Set this to true :)

Comment: nopes I ran into other problems, I put to false to solve many other issues that I was facing before.

Comment: plus reading the description I cant figure out how will it solve my problem.

Comment: It depends on what kind of keys do you use. Also, there is a http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee708924.aspx for using with issued token. And does your app has access to private key of cert, used for creating token? AFAIK Issuer must use public key for token issuance, and RP - private key for validation. Maybe Im wrong, but without info about ADFS setup it is hard to analize whole stack.

Comment: Also check this out http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/10/wcf-cannot-find-token-authenticator.html

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am using _channel.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token) The ADFS is configured to sign and encrypt the token, here is how i get the token this code might help in deciphering my problem.

 using (var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                    new KerberosWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                    new EndpointAddress(kerberosEndpoint)))
            {
                trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
                trustChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14326/discussion-between-ovais-and-alexey-anufriyev)

Answer (score 1):

Alexey's answer is perfect for web.config/app.config modifications. Besides that you can also configure the token handler in code (sample from the <s>[How to: Authenticate with a Username and Password to a WCF Service Protected by ACS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185954.aspx)</s> [(learn.microsoft.com) - How to: Authenticate with a User Name and Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-authenticate-with-a-user-name-and-password)):

```
//
// This must be called after all WCF settings are set on the service host so the
// Windows Identity Foundation token handlers can pick up the relevant settings.
//
ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();
serviceConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

// Accept ACS signing certificate as Issuer.
serviceConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = new X509IssuerNameRegistry( GetAcsSigningCertificate().SubjectName.Name );

// Add the SAML 2.0 token handler.
serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace( new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler() );
```

Comment: Sandrino this is exactly what I am doing

serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.Add(new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler());

still getting the error :(

Comment: I am using AddOrReplace and Add gives an error which means that this handler is already in the collection.